# Submitting Manuscript - TeX Archive With Figures

Tags: latex

I am submitting a paper in a journal. It is mentioned that I should submit "TeX archive with figures" ([1](http://prism.opticsinfobase.org/Author/AllowableFileTypes)). I cannot understand what exactly they want, or which type of files they want. I have a `.tex` file and some `.eps` figures.

I would be so grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Ask the journal in question.

Comment: Better suited to http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The link you posted requires one to log in to the journal submission system. There are some [alternative instructions](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ol/submit/templates/) which suggest zip or tar are what's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to ask the journal for clarification, but since there's no such thing as a ‘TeX archive’ the instructions as quoted don't make much sense. I'd presume that what they mean is simply a zip or tar file containing the `.tex` source, plus your `.eps` files.

I'd go with that, and if they bounce it back you can tell them they need to make their instructions clearer.